# Add products to inventory from "More" dropdown list in custom module Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to add a drop-down item that allows me to add the selected items from my module to the product list in the Inventory.

I followed this threat https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/call-function-from-the-more-dropdown-list-61330 and added this code:

```
<record id="dditem1_action" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Add to inventory</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_sync2ba_products"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="condition">True</field>
        <field name="code">if object: self.browse(cr,uid,context.get('active_ids', [])).your_function()</field>
</record>
<record id="dditem1" model="ir.values">
        <field name="name">brand</field>
        <field name="model">sync2ba.products</field>
        <field name="key" >action</field>
        <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
        <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,%d'%dditem1_action"/>
</record>
```

And:

```
_name = 'sync2ba.products'
_rec_name = 'ProductId'

Brand                           = fields.Char(string="Brand")

..... OTHER FIELDS

@api.multi
def your_function(self):
    for item in self:
        # do something with selected records
        print 'Hello'
```

And I get his error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 677, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 333, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 326, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 935, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 506, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1161, in run
    result = request.env['ir.actions.server'].browse([action_id]).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 974, in run
    res = func(action, eval_context=eval_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_actions.py", line 58, in run_action_code_multi
    res = super(ServerAction, self).run_action_code_multi(action, eval_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 795, in run_action_code_multi
    safe_eval(action.code.strip(), eval_context, mode="exec", nocopy=True)  # nocopy allows to return 'action'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0+e.20170828-py2.7.egg/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 301, in safe_eval
    return unsafe_eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: "name 'self' is not defined" while evaluating
u"if object: self.browse(cr,uid,context.get('active_ids', [])).your_function()"
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem is the field `code` in XML.
I saw, that it works for Odoo 9, but may by not for Odoo 10. You can try it:

```
<field name="code">
    if context.get('active_model') == 'sync2ba.products' and context.get('active_ids'):
        if object: 
            env['sync2ba.products'].with_context(context).browse(context.get('active_ids', [])).your_function()
</field>
```

- Odoo 10 use the new API. Your code uses the old API
- The variable `self` doesn't exist in Odoo 10

Comment: It looks that you are right. I just need to add the functionality and see if it works. Thank you.